# Very new in R, subsetting columns

Tags: r

I have a data set with many columns, I want to subset all the rows but just some columns
-from column 4 to the end

```
myselec<-mydata[ 1, 4:]
```

-some selected columns  e.g. 4, 5, 6, 10, 12

Can anyone provide some suggestions that how I can do this in R?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#columns 4 to the last one
myselec<-mydata[ 1, 4 : ncol(mydata)]

#put the columns you want to keep in a vector
columnsIWantToKeep <- c(4, 5, 6, 10, 12)
#subset your DFusing this vector
myselec<-mydata[1, columnsIWantToKeep]
```

The same applies to rows...

```
myselec<-mydata[ 4:nrow(mydata),] #get from row 4 to the end
myselec<-mydata[ c(1,3,5,7),] #get rows 1,3,5,7
```

You can even work by exclusion: tell the rows you *don't* want and R will give you all others.

```
DontWant <- c(1,3,5)
myselec<-mydata[ -DontWant ,]  #note the 'minus' symbol to denote that you wish to exclude these
```

Answer (score 0):

Leave the space before the comma blank to take all the rows. Pass a vector of column positions after the comma:

`mydata[, c(4,5,6,10,12)]`

Comment: Is it not considered *better* to not have the comma?

Comment: Better? If you don't leave the comma you will only subset the rows and not take all of them

Comment: Try `mtcars[c(1, 3, 5)]`. You subset the rows if you add a comma after

Comment: Well I'll be... I still think it's better to use the comma. It's clear that the object is not a vector. Thanks for the tip, though

Comment: I can see that. It does save typing out `drop=FALSE`, when you compare the result of `mtcars[1]` and `mtcars[,1]`. Im sure i have also seen some newer functions  / packages being a bit funny with the comma approach (might have imagined it though!)